# PDF is rendered as text content when trying to view pdf file in my browser

Tags: java, pdf, jsf, servlets, response

I have an error when I want to download or see in the web browser a pdf file, somehow the file is generated in text. Has anyone had this problem?

Is my code:

```
public void downloadPDF(File ArchivoPDF, String NombrePDF) throws IOException{

    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext.getResponse();

    BufferedInputStream input = null;
    BufferedOutputStream output = null;

    try{
        input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(ArchivoPDF),DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);

        response.reset();
        response.setHeader("Content-Type","application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-Length",String.valueOf(ArchivoPDF.length()));
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"" + NombrePDF + ".pdf\"");
        output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream(),DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
        int length;
        while((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0){
            output.write(buffer,0,length);
        }

        output.flush();
    } finally{
        close(output);
        close(input);
    }

    facesContext.responseComplete();
}

private static void close(Closeable resource){
    if(resource != null){
        try{
            resource.close();
        } catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and my component commandButton is:

```
<a4j:commandButton  id="btnGenerarAllPDF" style="width:130px;"
                rendered="#{clsGestionReclamoRealSrv.objComponente.blVerBtnGenerarExpedienteElectronico}"
                value="Generar Expediente"
                onclick="#{rich:component('modCargando')}.show();" 
                action="#{clsGestionReclamoRealSrv.doGenerarAllPDF}"
                oncomplete="#{rich:component('modCargando')}.hide();"
                reRender="frmRegistrarReclamo"/>
```

and call method in:

```
File ArchivoPDF = new File(pathFolderArch + String.valueOf(this.getObjReclamo().getNuIdReclamo()) + ".pdf");
if(ArchivoPDF.isFile()){
    ClsUtils.deleteCarpeta(pathFolderTemp);
    downloadPDF(ArchivoPDF,String.valueOf(this.getObjReclamo().getNuIdReclamo()));
} else {
    logger.error("Error al generar el PDF.");
}
```

and the result is text in browser.

[Text replace pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrHf0.png)

They know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the appropriate way to set the content type is something like,

```
response.setContentType("Content-Type","application/pdf");
```

This could download your file as `pdf` as expected. To view the file in browser try something like,

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + NombrePDF + ".pdf\";");
```

Comment: hi, change the target to _blank and it worked. You could do a pdf load without consuming a lot of bandwidth?